# How to change add/remove program name using WiX Installer?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

I'm building a WiX project to install a custom package. My product looks like this:

```
<Product
    Name="My custom project"
    ... />
```

So when I'm using the WiX installer, I can see the `Selected name` on my screens and whenever Wix uses the name to display.

Under **add/remove** programs, I can see the same name specified under `Name` tag. But I want it to look different, as:

```
My custom project v1.0
```

As far as I've seen, as Rob Menching mentioned [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Name-in-add-remove-programs-tp4262704p4263041.html), the way to do so will be modify my **.wxs** screen files to modify the `[ProductName]` tag and substitute it with my own selection.

I wonder if there is an easier and shorter way, for example, using my custom `ARPINFO` configurations, like the ones posted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368032(v=vs.85).aspx) to modify the name that appears under **add/remove programs list**.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: A shorter way than modifying the ProductName? It's not clear what the issue is here. ProductName is what you use, the rest of the ARP info is that set of properties at the link.

Comment: This is standard Windows Installer behavior—nothing to do with WiX created tables or WiX provided actions. You _can_ use [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367750(v=vs.85).aspx) to hide the entire entry and separately create your own entry. But are you sure this is a validated requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for this. Possibly you can find it useful in your scenario too.
For this approach you have to edit wixproject file i.e. *YOURPROJECT*.wixproj.
Edit the `Name` attribute under `PropertyGroup` tag.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>        
        <OutputName>YOURAPP.$(ProductVersion)</OutputName>
        <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
        <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
        <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
 <!--<This name will be displayed under your add remove program.>-->
        <Name>YOURAPP</Name>
        <!--<This is used for Product Display Name.>-->
        <Cultures>;</Cultures>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This is basically your project name. When `Name` attribute of `Product` tag in .wxi file is getting for updated dynamically then in that case your application name will not come from product tag, thus this is the option left to update your product name in add/remove programs.

Do comment if you need any help or more explanation.